# enable pgqsl extension PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, hosting, web-hosting

I am using Heroku postgres databae.I want to connect it to PHP in my cloud hosting.I am unable to access the php.ini file to enable the pgsql extension.The dl() function doesn't work.How can i connect to the postgres database?

Comment: Have you tried with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php)?

Comment: Check out the PHP PDO libraries. Information for the PostgreSQL extension can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php.

Comment: i tried PDO  'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' got this error